# I try to plot f(x) and g(x) on the same axis, but the plot is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I defined f(x)=sin(2x) and g(x)=2*sin(x). Then I try to plot f(x) and g(x) on the same axis, but the plot is blank. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my argument so far:

plot[{f(x),g(x)},{x,-1,1}]

Comment: You are making syntax mistakes.  Use square brackets "[]" to contain arguments to functions.  Also, `plot` needs to be capitalized.  I would recommend reading a quick introduction to Mathematica.

Comment: I would recommend you to read [the most common pitfalls awaiting new users in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users), in particular the _Basic Syntax_ section.

Comment: [The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html) and [Making Definitions for Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am OK with Chuy but the best thing is to look at code

```
f[x_] := Sin[2 x]
g[x_] := 2*Sin[x]
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

every command in mathematica begins with an uppercase. Forget ( for the functions. It must be defined with brackets or you must ask it to change its behavior.

Take a good how to on internet before going further.

Cordially